# How to figure out what makes my iOS app crash (EXC_BREAKPOINT)?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics, nscoding

How can I know where exactly did my app crash ?
I receive a lot of crash from my users but I can't reproduce the crash myself and the crash log does not indicate a specific line:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  myapp                  0x22d1d4 specialized ItemType.init(coder : NSCoder) -> ItemType? (ItemType.swift)
1  myapp                  0x22c72c @objc ItemType.init(coder : NSCoder) -> ItemType? (ItemType.swift)
2  EventKitUI                     0x234734a5 (Missing)
3  EventKitUI                     0x23479639 (Missing)
4  EventKitUI                     0x234161db (Missing)
5  EventKitUI                     0x234734a5 (Missing)
6  EventKitUI                     0x234728d3 (Missing)
7  myapp                  0x1e9df4 specialized Item.init(coder : NSCoder) -> Item? (Item.swift:162)
8  myapp                  0x1db9b8 @objc Item.init(coder : NSCoder) -> Item? (Item.swift)
9  EventKitUI                     0x234734a5 (Missing)
10 EventKitUI                     0x234728d3 (Missing)
11 EventKitUI                     0x23471bc7 (Missing)
12 myapp                  0x26f370 savedSearchList.getLastItem() -> Item! (savedItemList.swift:71)
13 myapp                  0x26c008 specialized MenuInitializerViewController.getSideMenuViewController() -> UIViewController (MenuInitializerViewController.swift:39)
14 myapp                  0x18388c SharedAppDelegate.showMainInterface() -> () (SharedAppDelegate.swift:427)
15 myapp                  0x18398c @objc SharedAppDelegate.showMainInterface() -> () (SharedAppDelegate.swift)
16 myapp                  0x188a48 SharedAppDelegate.(retreiveFirstData(SharedAppDelegate) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (SharedAppDelegate.swift:290)
17 myapp                  0x2657a4 partial apply for UserAppData.(getFirstData(UserAppData) -> (() -> (), failure : (error : NSError) -> ()) -> ()).(closure #3) (UserAppData.swift:45)
18 myapp                  0x263828 partial apply for thunk (UserAppData.swift)
19 myapp                  0x268c28 UserAppData.(getDiffusionsGroup(UserAppData) -> (() -> (), failure : (error : NSError) -> ()) -> ()).(successBlock #1)(AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject : AnyObject!)() (UserAppData.swift:788)
20 myapp                  0x266684 partial apply for UserAppData.(getDiffusionsGroup(UserAppData) -> (() -> (), failure : (error : NSError) -> ()) -> ()).(successBlock #1)(AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject : AnyObject!)() (UserAppData.swift)
21 libtzupdate.dylib              0x344ffe2f (Missing)
22 libtzupdate.dylib              0x344ffe1b (Missing)
23 libtzupdate.dylib              0x345046c9 (Missing)
24 CoreAudio                      0x226dc535 (Missing)
25 CoreAudio                      0x226daa2f (Missing)
26 CoreAudio                      0x2262d0d9 (Missing)
27 CoreAudio                      0x2262cecd (Missing)
28 GeoServices                    0x2b9a2af9 (Missing)
29 UIKit                          0x268b62dd UIApplicationMain + 144
30 myapp                  0x10f2d4 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
31 libtzupdate.dylib              0x34528873 (Missing)
```

I understand that it might come from ItemType unarchive initializer, but I don't see what could be wrong with it:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    self.index = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("index")
    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
    self.id = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("id") as! String
    self.type = Type(rawValue: aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("type")) ?? .Default
}
```

Comment: as per you log message i can guess, its in **UserAppData.swift** file, but i would suggest add **Exception Breakpoint** to get exact location on your project.

Comment: @RDC I can't reproduce the crash myself, so adding a breakpoint won't have any effect right ?

Comment: no effect, it will just help you to find out the crash point, just add break-point as suggested by @nestorgt

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Exception breakpoint and/or Swift error breakpoint in

```
View->Navigator->Show Breakpoint Navigator
```

and then click the + icon on the bottom

Comment: I can't reproduce the crash myself, so even if I add a breakpoint, it won't be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is helping but these two lines are not very safe code

```
self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
self.id = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("id") as! String
```

You are force casting the object as a String without checking if it has a value. ObjectsForKeys are nil by default until you set them the first time.
So these 2 lines can potentially cause a crash if you haven't set the object at least once. Try using the ?? nil coalescing operator to ensure this cannot happen.

```
self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String ?? self.name
self.id = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("id") as? String ?? self.id
```

Now you check if the object exits (as? String) and if it doesnt than it uses the default name/id (?? self.name)

I am not sure this is causing the crash but this should improve your code.
Your code to save the Enum seems alrite because you are using the ?? operator, so I dont think thats causing the issue.

You only need to do nil checks for ObjectsForKeys, because they are of type AnyObject and therefore dont know what object they actually are until set once, hence it could cause a nil crash.

Compare this to say BoolForKey where you dont have to do this because it knows you are dealing with boolean values and therefore it defaults to false automatically.

Also, you are doing the same thing I keep seeing here, which is not using constants for keys. This is just prone to typos.

Create a struct above your class

```
struct Key {
   static let name = "Name"
   static let id = "ID"
}
```

and than use the keys like so

```
...objectForKey(Key.name)
```

Hope this helps